Thriller movie about a woman who tries to kill her children
I saw this movie on TV a few years ago and I can't find it. I don't remember much but here it goes.
This mom (it may be the step mom) takes care of her husband's children or her children? The kids are pretty young. I think the girl is older maybe around twelve and the boy ten.  In the end I guess she tries poisoning them with a needle I think and the husband tries to stop her. I remember I think the little boy was skinny he didn't have a shirt on and I think she was neglecting them. In the end there was a big chase and attacking scene in the house between the dad and the mom because he found out. That's pretty much all I remember.
It may have come out in the early mid 2000's and it seemed like a made for TV, it felt a lot now looking back like a lifetime movie. It may have been a dramatization of a real life case if it were a lifetime movie.
I watched it with my mom and she said the little girl looked a bit like Lindsay Lohan if she were blonde, but honestly I dont remember any of their faces.

A lot of it sounds like Glass House: The Good Mother from 2006.

@Walt omg yes thats it I wow that was super quick thank you so so much its been bothering me forever but that's definatelyit!

No problem. I'll put it up (I wasn't 100% sure)

Glass House: The Good Mother from 2006 with Angie Harmon.

One year after losing their son David, Eve Goode and her husband Raymond Goode adopt the orphan Ethan Snow (and his teenager sister Abby Snow and bring them to their mansion nearby a lake. Abby faces difficulties of adaptation in her new home, and she confronts Eve, who proves to be deranged and unstable. When Ethan gets sick, Abby tries to contact their friend, detective Ben Koch, and she realizes that her brother and she are trapped in the house.




